# JavaScript - "Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null" Error

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript code gives an error. I searched but could not find. Maybe there is a problem with my jquery script that I use.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

var btnFront = btn.querySelector('.btn-front'),
  btnYes = btn.querySelector('.btn-back .yes'),
  btnNo = btn.querySelector('.btn-back .no');

btnFront.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var mx = event.clientX - btn.offsetLeft,
    my = event.clientY - btn.offsetTop;

  var w = btn.offsetWidth,
    h = btn.offsetHeight;

  var directions = [{
      id: 'top',
      x: w / 2,
      y: 0
    },
    {
      id: 'right',
      x: w,
      y: h / 2
    },
    {
      id: 'bottom',
      x: w / 2,
      y: h
    },
    {
      id: 'left',
      x: 0,
      y: h / 2
    }
  ];

  directions.sort(function(a, b) {
    return distance(mx, my, a.x, a.y) - distance(mx, my, b.x, b.y);
  });

  btn.setAttribute('data-direction', directions.shift().id);
  btn.classList.add('is-open');

});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/LoginCSS.css">
  <script src="../JavaScript/LoginJS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="btn-back">
      <p>Are you sure you want to do that?</p>
      <button class="yes">Yes</button>
      <button class="no">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-front">Delete</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help. Best wishes.

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery (`document.querySelector` is pure Javascript). Probably there is no element with class `btn` on the DOM when you are running this code. Did you wait for the document's `ready` event?

Comment: Thank you for information. I did not use document ready. I will try

Comment: See [this](https://flaviocopes.com/dom-ready/)

Comment: It happend. thank u so much ^^

Comment: distance is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `$( document ).ready(function()` and It happend.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   
var btn = document.querySelector( '.btn' );

var btnFront = btn.querySelector( '.btn-front' ),
    btnYes = btn.querySelector( '.btn-back .yes' ),
    btnNo = btn.querySelector( '.btn-back .no' );

btnFront.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
  var mx = event.clientX - btn.offsetLeft,
      my = event.clientY - btn.offsetTop;

var w = btn.offsetWidth,
      h = btn.offsetHeight;
    
  var directions = [
    { id: 'top', x: w/2, y: 0 },
    { id: 'right', x: w, y: h/2 },
    { id: 'bottom', x: w/2, y: h },
    { id: 'left', x: 0, y: h/2 }
  ];
  
  directions.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return distance( mx, my, a.x, a.y ) - distance( mx, my, b.x, b.y );
  } );
  
  btn.setAttribute( 'data-direction', directions.shift().id );
  btn.classList.add( 'is-open' );

} );

btnYes.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {   
  btn.classList.remove( 'is-open' );
} );

btnNo.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
  btn.classList.remove( 'is-open' );
} );

function distance( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
  var dx = x1-x2;
  var dy = y1-y2;
  return Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
}
});
```